# How can we use web workers of JS in salesforce lightning UI?

Tags: javascript, web, web-worker, salesforce-lightning

I'm trying to implement a web-worker thread in Salesforce Lightning UI but I got to know that **"According to the Locker Service API SecureWindow, ServiceWorker currently has a status of "Not To Be Supported". While this would be pretty cool to have, it's of pretty limited use in typical scenarios. Perhaps they'll review this in the future."**

*Is there any other alternative for this. I just need a background process to run which includes a for loop. As I'm using omni-channel I need the worker to be in the scope of lightning.*

Comment: What is your actual use-case? "[Background] process which includes a for loop" is too vague.

Comment: I need to update status of some cases (like 100) by calling an omni-channel API one-by-one. And this should work in background as it takes 300 seconds. Really dont want to show a loader and block the user for 300 secs.

Comment: @AKX I need to update status of some cases (like 100) by calling an omni-channel API one-by-one. And this should work in background as it takes 300 seconds. Really dont want to show a loader and block the user for 300 secs.

Comment: @AKX  need to update status of some cases (like 100) by calling an omni-channel API one-by-one. And this should work in background as it takes 300 seconds. Really dont want to show a loader and block the user for 300 secs